# Mongo $or query inside $and using Java MongoOperations

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to find records which are in active state using regex clause.

I need to find records by a string which is present at any location in user's full name *OR* email address.

I tried following mongo query and it is working perfectly as expected :

```
  db.getCollection('users').find({ $and : 
    [
     {"status" : "active"}, 
      { $or : 
        [ 
            {"fullName": /.*ri.*/}, 
            {"email": /.*ri.*/} 
        ] 
      }
    ] 
  } )
```

Here, I am searching a user in active state whose email or full name *contains* character "ri"

I tried converting the same in Java as follows :

```
 String regexSearch = ".*" + clauseForAutoSearch + ".*";
 Query findQuery = new Query();
 findQuery.addCriteria(
        Criteria.where("fullName").regex(regexSearch, "i")
        .orOperator(Criteria.where("email").regex(regexSearch, "i")).and("status")
        .is(UserStatusEnum.ACTIVE.getStatus())); // "active" string

  // "i" stands for case insensitivity. $options in mongo

  for (User user : mongoOperations.find(findQuery, User.class)) {
    userList.add(user);
  }
```

It yields **NULL** most of the times and it gives actual results only a few times.

Can someone please tell where I am going wrong ?

**EDIT** : Here "clauseForAutoSearch" is nothing but the string variable that I need to find in fullname/email of the record present.

e.g. there is a record named as Tom Cruise.
So, even if i enter "rui" or "is" it should show the record as the string is present in the fullname/email of the record

Comment: what is `clauseForAutoSearch` can you please show us what is the putput of  `regexSearch`

Comment: `.orOperator()` takes a list of `Criteria`. Just like the JavaScript sample you are trying to convert from.

Comment: @YCF_L : Editted the details

Comment: @NeilLunn : Okay, but can you kindly elaborate my mistake ?

Comment: @NeilLunn : I already tried that solution you suggested as "possible duplicate". didn't work with regex

Comment: @NeilLunn : Your comment solved it. I tried clubbing two criterias and it worked. IF you could write the answer, I ll be happy to accept it